# django pass argument from view to form only once

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, one-time-password

I have an OTP generator mechanism, whereby in GET method, a unique 4-dit OTP is generated and is sent to the OTPAuthenticationForm() as follows:

#### views.py

```
if request.method == 'GET':
   otp = 'abcd'
   # code to send otp via mail
   form = OTPAuthenticationForm(request=request, otp=otp) # this is how the OTP is passed only once.
   return ....
elif request.method == 'POST':
    form = OTPAuthenticationForm(request.POST, request=request)
    if form.is_valid():                 # the clean_field() method is not invoked/throws error.
       print("OTP is valid")
    else: 
       print("OTP is invalid")
```

#### forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


class OTPAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    otp = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput)

    def __init__(self, otp, *args, **kwargs):
       self.otp = kwargs.pop("otp")

       super(OTPAuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
       if self.otp!= self.cleaned_data['otp']:
          raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid OTP")
```

How should the generated_otp be passed only once to the OTPAuthForm() so that it could be validated against the user input OTP (OTP received via email).

**The clean() method is not getting invoked; instead on execution of form.is_valid(), the form return 'invalid' error**

Update:  The **OTPAuthenticationForm(forms.Form)** was earlier importing the class AuthenticationForm() which requires the username, password fields along with the custom OTP field.

Which is why the form.is_valid() was returning as invalid since the username, password auth was being separately handled in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not pass `otp` in `GET` request, instead it should by done by `POST` request:

```
form = OTPAuthenticationForm(request.POST, request=request, otp=otp)
```

And update the Form as well:

```
class OTPAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
    otp = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput)

    def __init__(self, otp, *args, **kwargs):
       self.otp_value = kwargs.pop("otp", None)
       super(OTPAuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
       otp = self.cleaned_data['otp']
       if self.otp_value != otp:
          raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid OTP")
       return super(OTPAuthenticationForm, self).clean()
```

Now, the question is how to store that OTP when you get the POST request. You can use session. Like this:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
   otp = 'abcd'
   form = OTPAuthenticationForm(request=request)
   request.session['otp'] = otp  # storing data in session
   return ....
elif request.method == 'POST':
    form = OTPAuthenticationForm(request.POST, request=request, otp=request.session.get('otp'))
    if form.is_valid():
        del request.session['otp'] # deleting data in session
        ...
```

Comment: your solution is good, however the clean() method is not getting invoked. I am still encountering invalid form error.

Comment: the variable is getting stored and retrieved in the session, but the clean() method is not getting invoked(found after debugging)

Comment: the OTPAuthenticationForm() must import forms.Form instead of the class AuthenticationForm if only the OTP fields needs to be validated.